# read large file in blogdown post

Tags: blogdown

I have a file large file of 400MB that I want to read in my blogdown post using Hugo. The problem is that I have netlify linked to the github repository of the website, but github places a maximum of 100MB per file, so I cannot upload the file. Is there anyway to read the file in the blogdown post using an URL instead, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could host the file elsewhere like in Dropbox. Let's say it's a `csv` file then you could get the Dropbox link to this file, say

`https://www.dropbox.com/s/RANDOMLETTERS/YOURFILE.csv?dl=0`

then the key is to change the `dl=0` to `dl=1` and read it in like

```
read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/RANDOMLETTERS/YOURFILE.csv?dl=1")
```